# General Sharepoint Development Question

Tags: sharepoint-2007

My company is rolling out Sharepoint 2007 Enterprise. I will not have admin access to the server. I will be given an account to use so I may make my departments website. Will I be able to use all of Sharepoint's features (workflow, searching, content management, developer level modifications) in the website I am building. Put another way, will I be able to develop any kind of dynamic website I want considering my department does not "own" the Sharepoint installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two approaches:

- To install your application as a feature; you'll need to run some `stsadm` commands and potentially some administrator permissions to activate it. This is recommended approach.
- To deploy your web application on a virtual directory, where you'll just need a file share permission to copy your files. This makes developer life easier.